# Can footer have header tag?

Tags: html, dom, header, footer

I have gone through a discussion regarding header and footer. As HTML5 provides header, footer, content elements, I believe it should be used once per page. I state them in following snippet.

```
<!-- My understanding -->
<header>
    <!-- code goes here -->
</header>
<content>
    <!-- code goes here -->
    <!-- code goes here -->
</content>
<footer>
    <!-- code goes here -->
</footer>
```

Few people have header, footer elements approach like below.

```
<!-- People understanding -->
<header>
    <!-- code goes here -->
</header>
<content>
    <!-- code goes here -->
    <!-- code goes here -->
</content>
<footer>
    <header>
        <!-- They also use <header> in footer. -->
    </header>
    <!-- code goes here -->
</footer>
```

Can `header` be used in `footer` element? In other words, What would you suggest to build a HTML structure?

Comment: the <header> element doesn't introduce a new section but is the head of a section and it is not required to using only one <header> element per site.

Comment: @BassJobsen that is true, however the HTML5 specification specifically states that `footer` elements must not have `header` descendants. My answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26357421/1317805) cites the relevant sections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this isn't valid.

The `header` element represents a header for the content, *however* the `header` element must not be a descendant of the `footer` element.

The `footer` section of the [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-footer-element) states that the `footer` element is:

> *Flow content, but with no `header`, `footer`, or `main` element descendants.*

If you paste the below code into [W3's HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) you'll get the following error:

> *Line 8, Column 20: **The element header must not appear as a descendant of the footer element.***

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <footer>
            <header>
            </header>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Ignoring the invalid `content` element, your first example is valid and you should stick with that instead.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you should stick to your first line idea:

```
// My understanding
<header>
    //code goes here
</header>
<content>
    //code goes here
    //code goes here
</content>
<footer>
    //code goes here
</footer>
```

For me, it is more easy way to understand how to make a HTML file on this format.

Answer (score 0):

The second example would *technically* work fine, as all of the `<header>`, `<content>` and `<footer>` functionally work similarly to `<div>`s, but semantically it'd be very bad practice. I'd go with your initial thoughts, which would certainly be the spirit in which those elements are intended.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header):

> The HTML  Element represents a group of introductory or
>   navigational aids. It may contain some heading elements but also other
>   elements like a logo, wrapped section's header, a search form, and so
>   on.

so I don't suggest you to use **footer** tag inside **header** tag.